# Flex doesn't build anymore?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have been working on a project for a long time now and there have been numerous situations in which I cannot seem to build.
I try 'clean', then I try building again.
Whether I do this manually or 'automatically' via saving it doesn't help anything.

This particular time I have no idea what to look for.

Can anyone shed some light on what the heck is happening?
Very frustrating.

Thanks,
jml

EDIT:

The main issue now seems to be the following error:

> File not found:
>   file:/yourhd/documents/flash_files/your_project/bin-debug/your_project.html

I understand that it can't find the html file, but i can't force it to rebuild it, no matter what i've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean that it won't build? Is there a build error?

If you have a compiler error, Flex won't build and you'll always be running old code when you debug, so make sure you take care of your source folder errors.

Comment: Ah, OK.  This is what I remember from a previous incident now.  Thanks for that.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused.
I would like to debug my project but I have no HTML file for flex to run the debugger with.  What do most people do in this situation?
I can't build the HTML file because flex won't build properly... The only indication I get of what might be wrong is found when I attempt to export a release build...

Comment: OK; I found the bug... not something that really has a solution AFAICT.  just a weirdness of flex that when you get into this particular situation you have to troubleshoot each class individually until you find your error.  sorta sux.

Comment: Remember, the problems panel will tell you exactly where your compiler errors are, so just make sure you have that panel visible while you code.

Comment: wow; i did not know bout the problems panel.  thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is happening because "something" happened to your bin-debug folder.

The fastest fix is to simply nuke the entire folder, then rebuild - FlexBuilder will recreate it for you.

Comment: this is what i had thought also-- i tried this and when it rebuilds the folder there is nothing in it!?

Comment: But does it rebuild successfully?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  This was the problem... I'm looking into troubleshooting it now.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a hung instance of FlashPlayer or your testing browser can cause this. Kill them in you task list (or other-OS equivalent)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion... unfortunately i don't think that's it.
:(

Comment: now i've created a new main project and attempted to copy my main runner's code into it... still nothing, PLUS i get a continual error regarding source folders that i've defined for my AS3 lib... hrmph.

Comment: i've updated my post to reflect the specific error i'm getting

Answer (score 0):

you just need to do a "clean" before doing a rebuild. it should regenerate the html template file.

Comment: well, i actually needed to debug. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this same thing happen a few times.  Everything's okay and then it just stops building. Clean doesn't fix anything and usually anything object I add in the MXML file suddenly isn't visible to the AS code.

There's probably something solveable but after fighting for a while I found it's quicker to just create a new project, copy everything and rebuild.

Comment: this question has already been marked answered.
please read the accepted answer as it contains information that will help you avoid rebuilding the project.

best,
jml